# React importing but not using in index.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting started with `reactJS`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var App = ()=>{
   return <div> Hello !!</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In every tutorial or project, everyone is doing `import React from 'react';`, but nobody is using `React` in the current file `index.js`.

Comment: So...what's the question? I've guessed at it below, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but using nowhere React in current file index.js

If the question is "Why does it has `import React from 'react'`?", the answer is: That source code isn't using `React` directly, but the version of it once it's transpiled is, because once the JSX is transpiled, that looks like this (if we **just** transpile the JSX, not the ES2015 stuff):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var App = () => {
   return React.createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      ' Hello !!'
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Note the use of `React.createElement`. The JSX `<App />` syntax is just sugar for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's probably because when transform jsx syntax, you can actually see for example: `<div className="exp"><img /></div>`, will transform into:

```
React.createElement('div', {className: 'exp'}, React.createElement('img'));
```

So, this will need React object.